# updata variable content

Tags: environment-variables

i'm editing network mount point script file. When the variable is assembed, it contains information, but when it is unmounted it appears empty, and if the script asks to assemble, the content of the variable does not update.

`VARIABLE=$(df -h | awk '{print $1}'| grep //user@IP/path/user)`

When unmounted:
`echo $VARIABLE` empty, if i mount with command:

```
open smb://user:passwd@IP/path/user
```

and type `df -h | awk '{print $1}' | grep //user@IP/path/user`
seem `//user@IP/path/user`
but if i give the check command
echo `$VARIABLE` seem empty

Someone can help me?

Comment: Instead of `awk '{print $1}'| grep //user@IP/path/user`, simplify to: `awk '/\/\/user@IP\/path\/user/ {print $1}' ` or to `grep '//user@IP/path/user' | cut -d' ' -f1`.

Comment: Can you provide a real example of your search pattern ?

Comment: It seems like you're expecting $VARIABLE to automatically update because the underlying condition (i.e. the mount) has changed.  Variables don't work like that, not even when using process substitution.   They're set to a value when you run the assignment command (which is evaluated at that moment in time), and only change when the assignment is run again, or some other command changes them.

Comment: @cas: yes, that could be the issue, but we don't know what the script is and how it's run. I thought its execution might be event driven or something like that, but it's impossible to determine without further input.

Comment: @JoseRicardoGaniko: please give us more detail per our questions in comments. Your question is ***unclear***.

Comment: @Cbhihe true enough, but I've seen new shell users make similar mistakes before in how they think about variables, so it seemed to be a likely explanation for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!!!
I really know that the variable is dinamic was the problem.
I managed to generate another variable call CHECK,
my code is not beautiful, I wanted you to return to check if it is mounted, to decrease lines of code.
Follow the my code shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
#Thunderbird Backup Script by VPN in MAC OS X

#Variables description
SOURCE=/Users/username/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/tsg0o7yk.default-release
TARGET=/Volumes/username
MOUNTED=$(df -h | awk '{print $1}' | grep //username@192.168.0.123/BackupThunderbird/username)
PATHDST='//username@192.168.0.123/BackupThunderbird/username'
SUCCESS='echo "YOUR BACKUP THUNDERBIRD WAS MADE!"'
ERROR='echo "COULD NOT PERFORM THUNDERBIRD BACKUP, CHECK LAN/WAN CONNECTIVITY AND AVALIABILITY OF THE UNIT STORAGE REMOTE STATUS"'
DATE=`date +%d/%m/%Y-%H-%M-%S`

#Connection test, if to fail will connect TunnelBlick
ping -c2 192.168.0.123 > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then
        echo "Connection OK time wait 30s for disconnect mount for test!"
    else
        echo "Disconected Tunnelblick, wait to connect..."
        osascript -e "tell application \"/Applications/Tunnelblick.app\"" -e "connect \"QNAP-MYVPN\"" -e "end tell" #call OpenVPN Tunnelblick MAC OS
        sleep 30
fi

backup () {
    echo "Please don't disconnect or unmount 192.168.0.123, running proccess backup..."
    rsync -rltpDhu $SOURCE/abook.* $TARGET 2> $TARGET/abook.log
    rsync -rltpDhu $SOURCE/history.* $TARGET 2> $TARGET/history.log
    rsync -rltpDhu --stats --delete-after $SOURCE/ImapMail/email-ssl.com.br $TARGET | mail -s "Report Thunderbird Backup" myemail@provider
sleep 30
    $SUCCESS | mail -s "$DATE - VPN Thunderbird Backup" username@localhost -c myemail@provider
    diskutil unmount /Volumes/username
}

no_backup () {
    echo "BACKUP COULD NOT BE PERFORMED, CONTACT YOUR ADMINISTRATOR"
    $ERROR | mail -s "$DATE - ERROR VPN Thunderbird Backup" username@localhost
} 


mount_function () {
    open smb://username:my_password@192.168.0.123/BackupThunderbird/username    # user remote unit storage 
    sleep 60
}

mounted () {
echo $MOUNTED
if [ $MOUNTED ]
    then
        echo "Mounted Unit"     
        backup  # call backup function
        exit
    elif [ !$MOUNTED ]
        then    
            echo "Unmounted Unit, mounting..."          
            mount_function  # call mount function
fi

CHECK=$(df -h | awk '{print $1}' | grep $PATHDST)
echo $CHECK
    
if [ $CHECK ]
    then
        backup
        echo "Script Verification when successfully"
    else
        no_backup
        echo "Script verification no successfully"
fi      
}
mounted
    
# Tunnelblick disconnecting
echo "Tunnelblick connection disconnecting"
osascript -e "tell application \"/Applications/Tunnelblick.app\"" -e "disconnect \"QNAP-MYVPN\"" -e "end tell"
```

Comment: Congratularions on figuring out the solution yourself. For verification of your script, you may want to open a question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Too bad you did not you provide your initial code early on (in OP); it  would have been useful, to understand and answer your original question. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @cas @Cbhihe!!
The solved issue by yours comments, so i undestanded the issue was variable.
Thanks too AdminBee.